# Using checkbox to enable/disable output

Tags: r, shiny

I am using `shiny` in R. I wish to use a checkbox to control whether a `numericInput` should be enabled.

```
library(shiny)

my_UI <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(numericInput("test", NULL, 1)),
  fluidRow(checkboxInput("chk", "NULL"))
)

my_Server <- function(input, output) {
  react <- reactive({
    input$chk
  })
  observeEvent(react(), shinyjs::disable("test"))
  observeEvent(!react(), shinyjs::enable("test"))
}

shinyApp(my_UI, my_Server)
```

However, the app does not always react to me checking/unchecking the box. Plus, sometimes the command is executed otherwise (i.e. enabled when checked and disabled when unchecked). Can anyone give me some guidance as to what is going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use observers as though they were if statements. The first argument to `observeEvent()` is a reactive expression, and whenever that expression invalidated, the observer will trigger. It doesn't matter if you have `react()` or `!react()` in there - the observer will trigger either way. To see this in action, add a print statement inside both observers, and you'll see that both of them are triggered every time you change the input.

What you are trying to do is this:

```
observeEvent(react(), {
    if (react()) {
        shinyjs::disable("test")
    } else {
        shinyjs::enable("test")
    }
})
```

This code chunk will enter whenever `react()` changes, regardless if it's TRUE or FALSE. Inside the observer you check for the value, and disable/enable accordingly.

An alternative and more efficient way to write this would be using `shinyjs::toggleState()`:

```
observeEvent(react(), {
    shinyjs::toggleState("test", condition = !react())
})
```

Comment: I definitely agree that this is a better option. I initially went this route with if else but somehow did not get it working. Now it does.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wrongly assumed that `eventExpr` in `observeEvent` is a logical statement, which, when turned true, will trigger `handlerExpr`. It works perfectly now!